# Is there a way to perform a test payment on a live site?

Tags: magento-enterprise

Does anyone have any methods to perform a test transaction on their live production sites, without it charging the user or sending the order to the warehouse?

Other platforms seem to have a method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is directly from the Magento Community Edition User Guide:

> **Testing Credentials**
>
> When testing the configuration of a payment gateway, use the following credentials for test transactions.
>
> **Visa**: 4111111111111111
>
> **MasterCard**: 5555555555554444
>
> **American Express**: 378282246310005
>
> **Expiration Date**: Any future date
>
> **CVV/CVC**: 123 or 000

Source: [Magento Documentation](http://magento.com/help/documentation)
[Test Credentials](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/test-credentials.html)

Comment: These links are now dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use test card numbers in your live site. 
However it will send the order data to Magento.

1. https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#test-credit-card-numbers
2. https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

I believe you can cancel the order in admin area once  you submit the order.

Answer (score 0):

Magento application test card numbers,
For CVC and CVV please use any 3-digit combination for Visa, Mastercard, Discover, Diners Club, EnRoute, and JCB; use a 4-digit combination for American Express.

[Reference article](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide.html)

[image]

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Magento?

Comment: these test credit card numbers can be used to place orders for testing in magento application. If your not finding it helpful, you can ignore